# Issue while building docker image on jenkins jnlp docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In the Jenkins Global tools configuration, I have selected docker installation as install automatically.

[image]

Below is the Jenkins pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build Docker') {
            agent {
                label 'jnlp-docker-agent'
            }
            tools {
                dockerTool 'docker_latest'
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    docker.build('demo-image:0.0.1')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting below error while building the job:

```
Downloading Docker client 17.09.1-ce
ERROR: Failed to download pre-1.11.x URL https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.09.1-ce from agent: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.09.1-ce
Unpacking https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.09.1-ce.tgz to /home/jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker_latest on jnlp-docker-002j7gw5ytuwc on docker
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t demo-image:0.0.1 .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

```
UPDATED:
```

In the Global tool, the configuration changed the docker version to 17.09.1-ce.tgz.

Below is the build output

```
Downloading Docker client 17.09.1-ce.tgz
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] { (hide)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t demo-image:0.0.1 .
/home/jenkins/workspace/DEMO Cloud/demo-image@tmp/durable-0b8b66d2/script.sh: 1: docker: Exec format error
```

Comment: May I suggest to use version ***docker-17.09.1-ce.tgz***? As the address is true that it does not exist, but adding .tgz extension yes.

Comment: Check Jenkins starts docker daemon or not after it help to install docker client to agent for you.

Comment: I have changed the version to 17.09.1-ce.tgz but getting error as shown above under "UPDATED:" section in the description